# JAXB in Java 9 module issues

Tags: java, jaxb, java-module

I'm upgrading our application to use Java 9 (baby steps... once we get 9 working, we'll jump to 10). One of the issues that we've run into is that at runtime, we're getting a module exception, and I can't seem to figure out what's going on. I'm admittedly new to modules, and have read all I can find about the topic, but I'm guessing this is probably a simple answer.

The runtime to invoke is

```
java --add-modules java.se,java.se.ee -cp mainjar.jar:jaxb-api.jar:jaxb-impl.jar:jaxb-core.jar foo.bar.Launch
```

The exception kicking out happens while attempting to read XML Data:

```
 WARN:09:22:10.777 [main] (Preference:969) - Failed to unmarshal preference value for key [launch.maxMemory]: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Package java.lang with JAXB class java.lang.Integer defined in a module java.base must be open to at least java.xml.bind module.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Package java.lang with JAXB class java.lang.Integer defined in a module java.base must be open to at least java.xml.bind module.
    at java.xml.bind@9.0.4/javax.xml.bind.ModuleUtil.delegateAddOpensToImplModule(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml.bind@9.0.4/javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml.bind@9.0.4/javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml.bind@9.0.4/javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml.bind@9.0.4/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml.bind@9.0.4/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Since Java 9, reflection has to play by the rules of the access modifiers. This means if a module is not open, access through reflection must obide the modifiers. In your case, `JAXB` seems to have trouble to read the `int value` of an `Integer`. You can open `java.lang.Integer` for `javax.xml.bind` by adding `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=java.xml.bin` to your `java` command. You can find more information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624).

Comment: See https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/1184

Comment: Turing85 - that fixed the problem here. If you make it into an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem.
I had my entities in `com.redeg` and the classes for working with XML in `com.redeg.xml` and adding a line `opens com.redeg.xml to java.xml.bind` to the `module-info.java` file helped.

`module-info.java`:

```java
module com.redeg {
    exports com.redeg;
    requires java.xml.bind;
    opens com.redeg to java.xml.bind;
    opens com.redeg.xml to java.xml.bind;
}
```